# WebObjects image caching

Tags: java, iis, webobjects

I want to cache the images returned by a WebObjects Java application on the client-side, by using the `Cache-Control` header.

The images are retrieved through calls like `/Scripts/WebObjects.dll/App.woa/1/wr?wodata=1_9840_th`

The web server uses IIS 8.5. I have tried to add the headers in the IIS configuration, without success. For some reason, they are not returned in the response.

The `WOApplication` is configured with `setPageRefreshOnBacktrackEnabled(true)`, though I don't know if that affects images. I can see that `cache-control: no-cache` is returned for normal action URLs, but not for images.

How can I make sure my images are being cached by the browser when using WebObjects? I could not find anything related to this in the the WebObjects developer guide or in the `WOImage` documentation.

Comment: I doubt that `setPageRefreshOnBacktrackEnabled` affects the resource request handler (as it doesn't deal with components).
When in doubt, you could always register your own request handler for the `wr` key (WOApp.registerRequestHandler) and compose the WOResponse on your own.

Comment: How can I find the existing handler for those requests? Is there a default handler for them in WebObjects?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, of course WO has a default handler for delivering resources. Should be named something like `WOResourceRequestHandler` and you can look it up by `WOApplication.requestHandlerForKey("wr")`.

Comment: @hnh Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. I was able to add the headers by using a custom request handler. Looks like there's not built-in support for this in WebObjects. Please add an answer to this question so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that `setPageRefreshOnBacktrackEnabled` affects the resource request handler (as it doesn't deal with components/pages).

When in doubt, you could always register your own `WORequestHandler` for the `wr` key (`WOApp.registerRequestHandler`) and compose the `WOResponse` on your own.

WO has a default handler for delivering resources which should be named something like `WOResourceRequestHandler` and you can look it up using `WOApplication.requestHandlerForKey("wr")`.